# url() vs route() in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

In my case, what is the difference between url() and route() in Laravel 5.6, two URIs are given below:

```
<a href=" {{ route('/article/create') }}" >Create post 1 </a>
```

and

```
<a href=" {{ url('/article/create') }}" >Create post 2 </a>
```

I defined them in web.php as follows:

```
Route::post('/article/create','ArticleController@create');
```

When I click on 'Create post 1' I got the following error:

```
Route [/article/create] not defined.
```

I am not familiar with Laravel (just basic) so I am sorry if the question is some kind of obvious.

Comment: The route helper function uses the route name. If you change your URL for some reason in the future, the route helper function will reflect that as long as the name of the route remains the same.

Comment: "I got errors": Please elaborate.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please explain the Create post 1 error

Comment: There is a good article in laravel-news about this: [Which Laravel Helper Do You Use for Your URLs?](https://laravel-news.com/which-laravel-helper-do-you-use-for-your-urls)

Comment: The error is "Route [/article/create] not defined. "

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's suppose you are using the same URL in 10 different place and later on, you decide to change it. If you're using named route you have to modify URL only in route file and all links will still work.

```
Route::post('/student/create', 'ArticleController@create')->name('student.create');
```

Now, instead of passing path to the url() function, you can use route name:

```
route('student.create'); // instead of url('/student/create');
```

Answer (score 11):

Define route with name

```
Route::post('/article/create','ArticleController@create')->name('article.create');
```

Now, `url()` will use path of route;

```
url('/article/create');
```

and `route()` will use name of route

```
route('article.create');
```

Answer (score -1):

So first of all i want to write a difference between URL's and Route in Laravel 5.6
In laravel Url's is to link the different pages of the website For example,

I want to go the create page in my website so the Url's is this,

```
<a href=" {{ url('/article/create') }}" >Create post 2 </a>
```

And the second is Route so in laravel Route accept the Url's and checked if Url's is right and give to the result

```
Route::get('/article/create', 'createController@create');
```

and if you want use Url's over Route and Route over Url's
like this

```
<a href=" {{ route('/article/create') }}" >Create post 1 </a> 

<a href=" {{ url('/article/create') }}" >Create post 2 </a>
```

you can use with Alias Route name

```
Route::get('/article/create', 'createController@create')->name('create');
```