# select link for tag a in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

which is the best way to use the method for passing the link to the a tag in laravel?

1)

```
<a href="{{url('dashboard')}}" class="active">Dashboard</a>
```

2. 

```
<a href="/register">Register a new membership</a>
```

3. 

```
<a href="{{route('welcome')}}">Home</a>
```

and when is it better to use a specific one?

Comment: It should answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50487047/url-vs-route-in-laravel-5-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tldr: 3

1. Just builds an url, "dashboard" is hardcoded an will not notify you when it no longer exists.
2. same
3. if the named route no longer exists, you get an error, way easier to not let this mistake happen.

Comment: i.e. it is always better to use 3?

Comment: Yes,  3 is more suitable for catching the error.